# Sum of reciprocal binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

I am aware that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}^{-1} = \frac{4}{3} + \frac{2\pi\sqrt{3}}{27}$$ 
though I do not know why it is true.  More generally, I'm interested in the value of the series 
$$S_k = \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{2n}{n-k}^{-1}$$ 
where $k$ is a fixed positive integer.  The series converges by the ratio test.  Does anybody know how to evaluate these sums, or have a reference where they are evaluated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally similar sums can be evaluated using the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function):
$$
B(x+1,y+1)=\int_0^1 t^{x}(1-t)^{y}dt=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(y+1)}{\Gamma(x+y+2)}=
\frac{x!y!}{(x+y+1)!}=\frac{1}{x+y+1}\binom{x+y}x^{-1}.
$$

Applying this in your case ($x=n-k,y=n+k$) one has:
$$
\binom{2n}{n-k}^{-1}=(2n+1)\int_0^1 t^{n-k}(1-t)^{n+k}dt
$$
or
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{2n}{n-k}^{-1}
&=\sum_{n=k}^\infty(2n+1)\int_0^1 t^{n-k}(1-t)^{n+k}dt\\
&=\int_0^1 dt \sum_{n=k}^\infty(2n+1)t^{n-k}(1-t)^{n+k}\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{(1-t)^{2k}[2+(2k-1)(1-t+t^2)]}{(1-t+t^2)^2}dt\tag1
\end{align}$$

It can be shown that the integral $(1)$ is a sum of a rational number and a multiple of $\dfrac\pi{9\sqrt3}$.

Indeed:
$$
\frac{(1-t)^{2k}[2+(2k-1)(1-t+t^2)]}{(1-t+t^2)^2}=Q_k(t)+\frac{A_k^0+A_k^1t+A_k^2t^2+A_k^3t^3}{(1-t+t^2)^2},\tag2
$$
where both coefficients of the polynomial $Q(t)$ and $A^0,A^1,A^2,A^3$ are integer numbers. The integral of $Q(t)$ is obviously a rational number and
$I_r= \int_0^1\frac{t^r\,dt}{(1-t+t^2)^2}$ can be evaluated as:
$$
I_0=\frac23+\frac49\dfrac\pi{\sqrt3};\quad 
I_1=\frac13+\frac29\dfrac\pi{\sqrt3};\quad
I_2=-\frac13+\frac49\dfrac\pi{\sqrt3};\quad
I_3=-\frac23+\frac59\dfrac\pi{\sqrt3}.\quad
$$

Thus the irrational term can be written as:
$$
C_k\frac\pi{9\sqrt3}\quad\text{with}\quad C_k=4A_k^0+2A_k^1+4A_k^2+5A_k^3.
$$

Moreover the term can be evaluated explicitly using the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
k\mod 3& A_k^0&A_k^1&A_k^2&A_k^3&C_k\\
\hline
0&+1-2x&+1+6x&-1-6x&+0+4x&2\\
1&+2+4x&-5-6x&+3+6x&-1-2x&\hphantom{-1}5+18x\\
2&-3-2x&2&0&-1-2x&-13-18x\\
\hline
\end{array},\tag3
$$
with $x=\left\lfloor\dfrac k3\right\rfloor$, so that $C_k=2,5,-13,2,23,-31,2,41,-49,2,\dots$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\dots$.

---

The expression $(3)$ can be proved in the following way:

Let
$$
P_k(t)=(1-t)^{2k}[2+(2k-1)(1-t+t^2)];\quad R_k(t)=A_k^0+A_k^1t+A_k^2t^2+A_k^3t^3.\\ 
$$

Then we have from (2):
$$R_k(t_\pm)=P_k(t_\pm);\quad R'_k(t_\pm)=P'_k(t_\pm),\tag4$$
where
$$
t_\pm=e^{\pm\frac{i\pi}3}
$$
are the roots of the polynomial $t^2-t+1$.

Explicitly (4) amounts to the system of four linear equations:
$$\begin{align}
A_k^0+A_k^1t_\pm+A_k^2t_\pm^2+A_k^3t_\pm^3&=2t_\pm^{-2k}\\
A_k^1+2A_k^2t_\pm+3A_k^3t_\pm^2&=(1-2k-2t_\pm)t_\pm^{-2k}\\
\end{align},
$$
which solutions are given by (3).

Answer (score 7):

Maple writes your sum as a hypergeometric function:
$$ S_k = {\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(1,1,1+2\,k;\,k+1,1/2+k;\,1/4)}$$

The values for $k=0$ to $3$ are
$$ \eqalign{k = 0: &{\frac{4}{3} + \frac {2\,\sqrt {3}\pi}{27}}
\cr
k = 1: &\frac13+{\frac {5\,\sqrt {3}\pi}{27}}
\cr
k = 2: &{\frac{23}{6}}-{\frac {13\,\sqrt {3}\pi}{27}}
\cr
k = 3: &\frac34+{\frac {2\,\sqrt {3}\pi}{27}}
\cr
}$$

Maple doesn't give a closed form for $k=4$ and up.  But I can get $k=4$ this way.
With $n = k + m$, write the summand as
$$ \frac{(m+2k)!\; m!}{(2m+2k)!} = \frac{m!^2}{(2m)!} \prod_{j=1}^{2k} \frac{m+j}{2m+j}  = 2^{-k}  \frac{m!^2}{(2m)!} \frac{\prod_{i=k+1}^{2k} (m+i)}{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (2m + 2i+1)}$$
Expand the quotient of products in partial fractions as a constant plus a sum of coefficients over $2m+j$.  Then sum individually.

That gives me
$$ S_4 = -\frac{211}{60} + \frac{23 \sqrt{3}\pi}{27}$$

but no farther since Maple won't give a closed form for 
$$ \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{m!^2}{(2m)!\; (2m+9)}$$
However, I think it should be possible to get closed forms for these: stay tuned....

EDIT: OK, it seems that

$$ F(z) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{m!^2}{(2m)!} z^{2m} = \frac{4}{4-z^2} + \frac{4z}{(4-z^2)^{3/2}} \arcsin(z/2) \ \text{for} |z|<2$$
so that
$$ \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{m!^2}{(2m)!(2m+j)} = \int_0^1 F(z) z^{j-1}\; dz $$

and these can be done in closed form.  So this gives me, for example,

$$S_5 = \frac{6169}{840} - \frac{31 \sqrt{3} \pi}{27} $$ 
and
$$ S_6 = \frac{1709}{2520} + \frac{2 \sqrt{3} \pi}{27} $$

Answer (score 1):

*Just to add more terms in the list.*
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & \frac{4}{3}+\frac{2 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 1 & \frac{1}{3}+\frac{5 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 2 & \frac{23}{6}-\frac{13 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 3 & \frac{3}{4}+\frac{2 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 4 & -\frac{211}{60}+\frac{23 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 5 & \frac{6169}{840}-\frac{31 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 6 & \frac{1709}{2520}+\frac{2 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 7 & -\frac{24923}{3465}+\frac{41 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 8 & \frac{3941153}{360360}-\frac{49 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 9 & \frac{7457}{11440}+\frac{2 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 10 & -\frac{26565167}{2450448}+\frac{59 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 11 & \frac{338662421}{23279256}-\frac{67 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 12 & \frac{29719175}{46558512}+\frac{2 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 13 & -\frac{5168552017}{356948592}+\frac{77 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 14 & \frac{40526745521}{2230928700}-\frac{85 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 15 & \frac{50607208969}{80313433200}+\frac{2 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 16 & -\frac{42190362918239}{2329089562800}+\frac{95 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 17 & \frac{3146154503067509}{144403552893600}-\frac{103 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 18 & \frac{2312776975921}{3702655202400}+\frac{2 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 19 & -\frac{1570173112141273}{72201776446800}+\frac{113 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 20 & \frac{27153272350852367}{1068586291412640}-\frac{121 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 21 & \frac{473757364639811}{763275922437600}+\frac{2 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 22 & -\frac{132365433369215539}{5215718803323600}+\frac{131 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 23 & \frac{1183965646415001041}{40777437916893600}-\frac{139 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 24 & \frac{63942535017037643}{103511957789037600}+\frac{2 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 25 & -\frac{20848468248125325229}{718702343285249700}+\frac{149 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}}
   \\
 26 & \frac{101214560276297183097311}{3099044504245996706400}-\frac{157 \pi }{9
   \sqrt{3}} \\
 27 & \frac{3717806717925956611}{6041022425430792800}+\frac{2 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 28 & -\frac{1340201691907238426586179}{41062339681259456359800}+\frac{167 \pi }{9
   \sqrt{3}} \\
 29 & \frac{26967769215388607878493}{743209767986596495200}-\frac{175 \pi }{9
   \sqrt{3}} \\
 30 & \frac{100780402282112197484981}{164249358725037825439200}+\frac{2 \pi }{9
   \sqrt{3}}
\end{array}
\right)$$